# Create metaboxes based on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, metabox, plugin-types

I am using [Metabox](https://metabox.io/docs/) to create metaboxes for Worpdress Post and it works like a charm. Now I have installed [MetaBox Custom Post Type Extension](https://metabox.io/plugins/custom-post-type/) for create CPT and it works good to. I have [Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) plugin installed for same purpose, create CPT so I can work either with Metabox or Types. I have created a CPT with slug `publicity` and I want to add some Metaboxes only to that CPT. How I can achieve this? I know how to create the Metaboxes using the plugin I just don't know how to make a difference between Wordpress post and this custom post type, perhaps by adding some conditional at `functions.php` and checking for post type slug and then including needed files but not sure and I need some push, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining your MetaBox before registering it, just set the PostTypes it is applicable for:

```
$f711_meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'details',
    'title' => __( 'Details', 'f711_theme' ),
    'pages' => array( 'publicity' ), // change this values
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(

        array(
            'name' => __( 'Fischi ist', 'f711_theme' ),
            'desc' => __( 'Jaja, Beschreibung', 'f711_theme' ),
            'id' => 'f711_is',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array( __( 'gut', 'f711_theme' ), __( 'super', 'f711_theme' ))
        )

    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( 'your_cpt' == get_post_type()) { ... }
```

or

```
if (is_singular( array('your_cpt'))) { ... }
```

`is_singular()` is only true when on a single post page. If you're on an archive page, you need `is_post_type_archive('your_cpt') { ... }`

Here's a list of useful [WP Conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).